# get all values from dictionary

Tags: linq.js

I'm using linqjs in my website and I'm trying to get all values of a dictionary populated with `toDictionary()` library extension.

Here is my code:

```
var imagesDictionary = Enumerable.from(data)
    .select(function (x) {
        var images = Enumerable.from(x.ImagesSections)
            .selectMany(function (y) {
                return Enumerable.from(y.Images)
                    .select(function (z) {
                        return z.Thumb;
                    });
            })
            .toArray();

        return { Title: x.Title, Images: images };
    })
    .toDictionary("$.Title", "$.Images");

var imagesToPreload = imagesDictionary.toEnumerable()
    .selectMany("$.Value");
```

I would that *imagesToPreload* become an array of all images contained in the dictionary but I can't understand how to do that and this:

```
var imagesToPreload = imagesDictionary.toEnumerable()
                .selectMany("$.Value");
```

seems the way than everyone used to obtain that.

Could someone help me?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you're using the linqjs 3 beta version, the format of the entries have changed.  The properties are in lowercase now.

```
var imagesDictionary = Enumerable.from(data)
    .toDictionary("$.Title",
        "Enumerable.from($.ImagesSections).selectMany('$.Images', '$$.Thumb').toArray()"
    );

var imagesToPreload = imagesDictionary.toEnumerable()
    .selectMany("$.value") // lowercase 'value'
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! Quite simple :)